# cannot move all files at once

Tags: cmake, mv

I am trying to move files inside one folder to another folder. However it just won't work for me. I have several cpp files and subfolders that I want to move. However if I want to move everything with `mv * ../somefolder` it says cannot stat ´*´.

If I only move a specific file it works, e.g. `mv file.cpp ../somefolder` but if I try `mv *.cpp ../somefolder` it gives me the aforementioned error. Why is that?

Some context: I am using ExternalProjet_Add_Step in CMake.

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    MonoEngine
    copySource
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MONOENGINE_DIR}
    DEPENDEES createFolders
    COMMAND mv MonoEngineSource/src/* MonoEngine
    COMMENT "Moving src to MonoEngine folder"
)
```

Comment: Remove the * and try with `mv MonoEngineSource/src`

Comment: @LnxSlck: If I do that, the `src` folder will be moved too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the command:

```
eval mv MonoEngineSource/src/* MonoEngine
```

to strip off the implied quoting.